# Gearman Cannot connect to server

Tags: php, pecl, gearman

Does anyone have any idea what could be causing this problem in Gearman?

> PHP Warning:  GearmanClient::doBackground():
>   gearman_connection_flush:could not connect

I am trying to connect to another server to run a gearman task and I am using the PECL PHP Gearman package.

Comment: Have you tried telnetting to the server or viewing the Gearmand verbose output?

Answer (score 1):

It's an old question, but for anyone who encounters this: your Gearman daemon may not be running. Do `gearmand -d` to set up the daemon first, then start your worker process, then finally run the client code.